# How to Get Date and Time String from Google Spreadsheet as String?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get Date and Time data from my Google SpreadSheet by Flutter HTTP Get method.
However the problem is when I read it, Date and Time is read as different format.
For example,
In Google Sheet, only '2020-11-27' is written. But when I read it from Flutter, it reads '2020-11-27T00:00:00Z'.
I tried data casting to string but now I got 'Mon Jan 13 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0900'.
Is there anyone can help me to read it just as it is? I mean String format.

And time is also the same.
I wrote only 11:10 in Google Sheet, but when I read it from Flutter, it says 1899-12-30 11:42:08.
I have now idea where the time come from...

Please find my code below and help me.
Thank you.

**Google Spread Sheet Data.**

```
test    2020-01-13  11:10   2022-11-01  3:03
```

**Google Script Code**

```
function doGet(request){
  var data = [];
  
  // Open Google Sheet using ID
  var SpreadSheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");

   // Get all values in active sheet
  var Sheet = SpreadSheets.getSheetByName("Data");
  var values = Sheet.getDataRange().getValues();  
  
  // Iterate values in descending order 
  for (var i = values.length - 1; i > 0; i--) 
  {
    // Get each row
    var row = values[i];

    // Create object
    var feedback = {};
    
    // ↓ String Casting and Org assignment. Both are not okay.
    feedback['DepartureDate'] = row[1].toString();    
    feedback['DepartureTime'] = row[2].toString();    
    feedback['ArrivalDate'] = row[3].toString();
    feedback['ArrivalTime'] = row[4].toString();
    //feedback['DepartureDate'] = row[1];
    //feedback['DepartureTime'] = row[2];    
    //feedback['ArrivalDate'] = row[3];
    //feedback['ArrivalTime'] = row[4];

    // Push each row object in data
    data.push(feedback);
  }     
 
  // Return result
  return ContentService
  .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(data))
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

**Flutter HTTP Get Code**

```
Future<List<DriveRecordForm>> getData_Easy() async {
    final response = await http.get(URL);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var temp = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);   // I checked response.body and the date and time is diffent from my expectation. (Expecation: 2020-01-13 / Result: Mon Jan 13 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0900...
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues), Google will interpret the cell content and give you the types it thinks are correct.

> The values may be of type Number, Boolean, Date, or String, depending on the value of the cell.

Use [`getDisplayValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) if you want to get the values exactly as they appear in the spreadsheet (as strings).